# How to clear a DatePicker

Tags: javafx

I have a **DatePicker** for selecting birthday.

This is going to be used for some filtering, and after the filtering, I will like the value to be ***reseted, i.e. the DatePicker should go blank.***

Any help???

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to clear the `TextField` of the `DatePicker`, you can use :

```
datepicker.getEditor().clear();
```

If you want to clear the value and the textfield, use :

```
datePicker.setValue(null);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and the editor gets cleared. But the problem still is that, thought nothing is shown on the editor, the value associated with that datepicker still remains the same as the previous value before clearing.    In a nutshell, it just clears the display but the date is still there.

Comment: Thanks, the combination of the two solves the problem.

Comment: When I put `datePicker.setValue(null);` I get a `NullPointerException` error.

Comment: @MakPo Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a separate question :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the the value of a datepicker to its default value or the current date you can use this

```
datepicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
```

or if you want to clear the textfield of the datepicker`

```
datepicker.getEditor().clear();
```

Answer (score -3):

just add this code

```
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
    }
});
```

You can use backspace to clear field even if it has in read only mode.
[Source](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3999#comment:21)

Comment: the question is about javafx, not jquery (or whatever your snippet is ;)